# Angular script open in browser on port 3000 but it points to port 8383

Tags: angularjs, node.js, port

I have been writing scripts in Angular over the past few weeks, using tutorials.  Most always this works fine.

The issue is that when I Run my script, the browser is Not pointing to port 3000.

Following are
-commands from terminal showing that I have started the server and I am listening on port 3000.
-the code that shows port 3000

I am on a Mac and from terminal, I navigate into the project file and type

```
node server.js
```

to start the server.   It returns

```
listening on port3000
```

I am following a tutorial today and although I am listening on port 3000 and within my server.js file I have the code

```
app.listen(3000);
console.log('server running on port 3000');
```

The URL is showing port 8383

node code:

terminal.

```
macbookpro:projectNodeMichael shane$ cd public_html/
macbookpro:public_html shane$ ls
angular.js  index.html  public
controllers node_modules    server.js
macbookpro:public_html shane$ node server.js
server running on port 3000
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//app.get('/', function (req,res){
//    res.send('hi from server.js');
//});

// set up html template using an express command
// static is html css and javascript files
// static means tell the server to the static files because they do not change
// dirname is the location

   app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

   app.get('/contactList',function(req,res) {
    console.log('I received a get request')
   });

app.listen(3000);
console.log('server running on port 3000');
```

controller.js

```
// connect our controller.js file with our index.html file
// test it is working properly

function AppCtrl($scope, $http) {
    console.log("hello world from controller")
    $http.get('/contactList')
    person1 = {
        name: "tim",
        email: "tim@email.com",
        number: '222 222-2222'
    };
    person2 = {
        name: "jim",
        email: "jim@email.com",
        number: '333 222-2222'
    };
    var contactList =[person1, person2, person3];
    ($scope.contactList) = contactList;    
}
```

index.html

index.html

```
        <div class ="container" ng-controller = "AppCtrl">
        <h1>Contact List App</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> name</th>
                <th> email</th>
                <th> number</th>     
                </tr>
            </thead>  
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat = contact in contactList>
            <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.number}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table></div>
        <script src ="angular.js"></script>
       <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
```

Can someone please clarify what I am missing here.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This seems ot have nothing to do with Angular, and can only be solved by sharing your Node code

Comment: What do you mean the URL is showing port 8383? Where is the URL coming from? What happens when you go to localhost:3000?

Comment: Most of the code you provided in the question is irrelevant, other than the express code. Can you try to better explain where you see 8383?

Comment: @simonH  I have added all the code and an image from imgur of the browser output. http://i.imgur.com/ayEer1I.jpg     who is down-grading this post.  it is relevant.  paths in technology are confusing at times. - yes ? thanks for helping

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck  Kris when I type localhost:3000 the browser output is Cannot GET /

Comment: @KevinB  here is a link to imgur that shows the browser output and the chromeDev errors.  I know a lot of this stuff but just stuck today and I dont like to quit :)

Comment: What link? i don't see any link. ( i also don't follow external links )

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ayEer1I.jpg  It didn't take when I did the edit. sorry. i will try and add it to the top of the original post again.

Comment: Can you try to better explain where you see 8383?

Comment: 2 people have view the imgur link successfully.  it is an image of the browser output.  the url shows localhost:8383/

Comment: What url? the one in the address bar? are you saying your browser is redirecting you after you type in localhost:3000? that could have been quickly expressed without an image... Tell us what you are doing, what the result is, and what you expected the result to be. I don't understand why this is so difficult.

Comment: do you have another app running on the 8383 port? there is nothing in the image or in your code to indicate that this is indeed the same instance of the app

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the code you have posted so far that can help us explain the port issue, but your picture shows that you have angular errors due to not creating a module and not defining a controller on the back of that. See this snippet for the sort of formatting needed:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('AppCtrl' function ($scope, $http)....
```

Comment: thanks again,  the  angular code I can sort out.  I have a bunch of similar scripts that work.  I am just very confused about why I am not launching from the node port 3000.  If you come up with something I would be grateful.  I need to step away for a while if you know what I mean.